# How to move from 1 recyclerview fragment to its own activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

My current recycler view has 2 fragments. i used a relative layout encapsulating 2 textviews for each fragment within the xml file used by the adapter.

My problem now is this; how do i make it such that when i click on each fragment, i can move to its unique location. Like from option 1 -> screen 1(activity), option 2 -> screen 2(activity 2).

Someone please help and explain to me step by step. i just started learning android app development 4 days ago.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nuts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nutrients" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nuts"
            android:text="Description" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The above is the xml filed i used for the adapter. The view is just for a line separator.

```
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_names, parent,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.names.setText(info.get(position).getName());
        holder.desc.setText(info.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView names, desc;
        private RelativeLayout parent;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLay);

            names = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nuts);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        }
    }
```

Currently, this are my adapter methods, did not post the constructor(it just takes in context) and getItemCount() method since i think they wont affect much? If they would then let me know, i would post them too.

As you can see, since i set the entire relativelayout(parent) with an onClickListener, once i click on it, it shows the toast message(this is for trying purposes).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nutrient_source);
        recyclerViewNuts = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNuts);

        ArrayList<Information> info = new ArrayList<>();
        info.add(new Information("Protein", "Makes you strong!"));
        info.add(new Information("Carbohydrates", "Provides Glycogen for energy"));

        nutsAdapter adapter = new nutsAdapter(this);
        adapter.setInfo(info);

        recyclerViewNuts.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerViewNuts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

This is the activity in which these relativelayouts reside in. i have 2 options, protein and carbs. When i press on protein, i need it to go to its protein related page, and carbs to its own carb related page.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i managed to find a way. For those who are curious or have similar problems, i passed the position of the recyclerview into a int variable, and wrote IF statements.

```
if(position == 0){
//go to activity1
}
if(position ==1){
//go to activity2
}
```